# Getting an error where float object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Hi I am new to `python and pandas`. Here I have the data in the following format

```
A                             B
[2000.0, 2000.0]          [2200.0, 0.0, 2200.0]
[2200.0, 0.0, 0.0]        [2200.0, 2200.0, 2200.0]
[2200.0, 2200.0, 2200.0]  [2200.0, 2200.0, 2200.0]
[200.0, 200.0, 200.0]     [200.0, 0.0, 200.0]
[160.0, 160.0, 160.0]     NaN
```

Here I am trying to compare the two arrays with equal and unique case

```
[2200.0,2200.0,2200.0] and [2200.0, 2200.0, 2200.0]
```

should return the `true`

but 
[2200.0,0.0,0.0] and [2200.0,0.0,0.0] should return me the `false`. SO, is there any way to do this ?

```
----> 2     if set(A) == set(B):
```

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: What is `A` (or `B`)?  The error says that one is a number.  `set()` expects something like a list.  What exactly are you showing at the top?  Is that a display of a dataframe?,  with columns named 'A' and 'B'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can replace missing values by empty lists before comparing:

```
df_out[['A','B']] = df_out[['A','B']].applymap(lambda x: [] if x != x else x)
```

Or:

```
df_out[['A','B']] = df_out[['A','B']].applymap(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [])
#alternative
#df_out[['A','B']] = df_out[['A','B']].applymap(lambda x: [] if isinstance(x, float) else x)
```

---

```
print (df_out)

                          A                         B
0     [2000.0, 2000.0, 0.0]     [2200.0, 0.0, 2200.0]
1        [2200.0, 0.0, 0.0]  [2200.0, 2200.0, 2200.0]
2  [2200.0, 2200.0, 2200.0]     [200.0, 200.0, 200.0]
3     [200.0, 200.0, 200.0]       [200.0, 0.0, 200.0]
4     [160.0, 160.0, 160.0]                        []
```

**Testing**:

```
def comp(A,B):
    try:
        a= set(A)
        b= set(B)
        return ((a == b) and (len(a) == 1) and (len(b) == 1))
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

Or:

```
def comp(A,B):
    try:
        return (set(A) == set(B)) and (len(set(A)) == 1) and (len(set(B)) == 1)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

---

```
for ins, rw in df_out.iterrows():
    val = comp(rw.Previous_Three, rw.Next_Three)
    print (val)
    False
    False
    True
    False
    False
```

Comment: for ins, rw in df_out.iterrows():
    if set(A) == set(B):       
Actually i am doing in the loop only this  checking , Don't want to create a new df. Just if itis equal then do something or else

Comment: Hey, One thin is that If I have to check an array which will check that both should have the equal and unique values. like  [200,200,200] and [200,200,200]  should return true but [200,0,200] and [200,0,200]  should return false

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - OK, if question was changed, please post new question.

Comment: @GaneshKaspate How come "[200,0,200] and [200,0,200] should return false"? They are identical to each other.

Comment: yes they are but the values in first and second are not equal

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - OK, please create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Edited answer you mean to say ?

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - exactly.

Comment: Actually I added the way I used in the my answer.. Please check as it the way

Comment: By mistake I edited that.. I was adding that in the question irself

Comment: It is returning false for everywhere even if it is matching with the condition

Comment: [100.0, 100.0, 100.0] [100.0, 100.0, 100.0]
False    like this it is giving me an error . Length attribute is not working I thinbk

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - hmmm, you are right, so answer was edited.

Comment: can you please tell me what we did I mean we changes it to set

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - there was some parentheses mismach, now working and added to answer.

Comment: okay thanku very much..   what if I want to try for 2 values encompassing zeros 100,100 on both sides

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - Can you explian more?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in the question that you want to know for each row if the unique values of column `A` and `B` are the same, use:

```
df_out['is_same'] = df_out.apply(lambda x: set(x['A']) == set(x['B']), axis=1)
```